# Cut Circular Dashed Holes into a Disc

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create something a bit like this. How could I go about creating multiple dashed holes, which follow a circular path, into a disc?

[image: Polyphon Music Box]
[image: Dashed Holes]

Comment: do you need to recreate the exact same pattern or just something that looks like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Turn your bitmap image to a svg with Inkscape or Illustrator (see a tutorial on bitmap tracing, it's very easy). If you don't know .svg is a standard format for vector images, which will allow blender to interpret the image as curves.
2. Import svg in blender, convert to mesh, add a solidify modifier (in the modifier turn ON "On Cage" and delete all vertices that behave weirdly if you have any, make sure you don't accidently delete faces)
3. Make a circle with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, subdivide it 4 or 5 times, add a Boolean modifier targeting your imported svg and you should get this

[image]

Here is the .blend file: [image]

Comment: Many thanks for this method, looks great. I'm having a of couple issues though...

When I import my .svg the dashes are being converted to separate curves, 154 of them. How do I group them and add Solidify all at once? Also cannot see 'On Cage' - using 2.8. See > https://ibb.co/G9996Kk

Comment: Sussed it.. Bool Tool add-on, then Union all the objects.

Comment: @Jamie I convert them all to mesh then CTRL+J to join, then if needed I select all vertices and press F to create faces, then join vert by distances as there is usually wait too many (kind of like decimating the mesh and it helps the cleaning process). Finally solidify and bool